# How cut image like this in HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering how to cut the image to put beside a text like this example: [image]

Comment: We expect you have made some search on SO or on google..... and please show us [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's way too easy.
The only thing you need to know is the `clip-path` property.

[Click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to visit MDN Page.

```
img {
    clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

You can use this code.

Example:

```css
img {
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614102073832-030967418971?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8bGFuZCUyMHNjYXBlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
```

Also, [Click Here](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) to see a `clip-path` generator.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `clip-path`

```css
img {
clip-path: polygon(31% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/500/300"/>
```

There is a tool you can use [Click Me](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)